# ServiceStack RedisServerEvents must start RedisPubSub server even for a client component

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

[ServiceStack RedisServerEvents](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/RedisServerEvents.cs) implementation ties the server component with the client component. There is no way to just run a client side component which
just publishes messages on ServiceStack Server Event channels without having to
start up the entire RedisPubSub server which also starts up a local MemoryServerEvents server.

Temporary Workaround:
  I copy the code for the client implementation of 'Publish' (NotifyChannel, NotifyUserId, etc) to a private module.

Question:
  Is this a potential design issue or am I not using the RedisServerEvents correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Redis Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Redis-Server-Events) is the back-end server component for hosting real-time SSE connections which enables ServiceStack Server Events to work across multiple load-balanced App Servers. The [C# Server Events Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-Server-Events-Client) is the client component and what allows you to subscribe to a ServiceStack Server Events instance, join channels, handle messages, etc.

It's not clear on exactly what your after, but if you just want to call ServiceStack Services via Redis you may instead be looking for [Redis MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) which is completely separate to Server Events which lets you publish Request DTO's without needing to configure a Server on the client:

#### [RedisMQ Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis#redismq-client)

Clients can use a `RedisMessageProducer` to be able to publish a message, e.g:

```
var redisManager = new RedisManagerPool("localhost:6379");
using (var mqClient = new RedisMessageProducer(redisManager))
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "Client 1" });
}
```

Or if preferred can instead use a `RedisMessageFactory` which provide access to both [IMessageQueueClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Messaging/IMessageQueueClient.cs) and [IMessageProducer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Messaging/IMessageProducer.cs):

```
IMessageFactory redisMqFactory = new RedisMessageFactory(redisManager);
using (var mqClient = redisMqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "Client 1" });
}
```

It would still require a [Redis MQ Server to be started on the Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis#example) but the client only needs to be able to publish to a Redis instance.